# Crystal Report Using List Items

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Can anyone help me to get the result in crystal report as displayed in the image where I have 3 tables.

Would it possible to show to bill in crystal report with the help of RecordSelectionFormula? Other method will also work.

[Click here for Image with tables and bill format required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNH2d.png)

Comment: Can somebody help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a group on Bill NO. and set ID and Item Name in Details.

Comment: Then How will I call them for printing for any particular Bill No.? Is this possible with record selection formula? Like cryRpt.RecordSelectionFormula= "{Table2.OrderNumber}" in List 'here list contains all the order number like ["5", "7", "9"]

Comment: When creating a group, by default you will see "in asceding order".

 Switch to "specified order" and then create a "named group"

Choose from the list: "is one of" and set the values (5, 7, 9).

Comment: The set values (5,7,9) are not fixed, these will kaeep changing on run time for every bill

Comment: Then its only when 'Bill No' is 'A1' ? you can do that in the group as well. Follow the same instruction but set Bill No "is equal to" .

Comment: Would it be able to select any bill number on run time? My requirement is when I select any bill no. on run time it should retrieve all the order numbers with the item details. Suppose we have restaurant business where one table can have placed mumtiple orders for food, however the single bill will be generated for all the orders.

Comment: Go to Field Explorer - Parameter Field
Right Click » "new Parameter" and choose the field you want (Bill No) you can also set prompt text and other options below.